# TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined | Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, node-modules

Making a new bot for my server and this error wont stop showing:

**error:**

```
(node:9340) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined
    at new WebSocketConnection (C:\Users\My\Path\To\Success\Visual Studio code\Discord Bots\Testing\Second Try\Intents\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:60:23)
    at WebSocketManager.connect (C:\Users\My\Path\To\Success\Visual Studio code\Discord Bots\Testing\Second Try\Intents\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:75:25)
    at Client.login (C:\Users\My\Path\To\Success\Visual Studio code\Discord Bots\Testing\Second Try\Intents\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:220:21)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

I've looked at my other bots and their location of error which this bot is outputting and it all looks the same to me.

**Code:**

```
class WebSocketConnection extends EventEmitter {
  /**
   * @param {WebSocketManager} manager The WebSocket manager
   * @param {string} gateway The WebSocket gateway to connect to
   */
  constructor(manager, gateway, client) {
    super();
    /**
     * The WebSocket Manager of this connection
     * @type {WebSocketManager}
     */
    this.manager = manager;

    /**
     * The client this belongs to
     * @type {Client}
     */
    this.client = manager.client;

    if (typeof client.options.disabledEvents == 'object' && typeof client.options.disabledEvents[Symbol.iterator] == 'function')

    /**
     * The WebSocket connection itself
     * @type {WebSocket}
     */
    this.ws = null;

    /**
     * The current sequence of the WebSocket
     * @type {number}
     */
    this.sequence = -1;
```

**Other References to "options":**

```
109:    /**
110:     * Whether or not the WebSocket is expecting to be closed
111:     * @type {boolean}
112:     */
113:    this.expectingClose = false;
114:    for (const event of this.client.options.disabledEvents) this.disabledEvents[event] = true;

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

135: /**
136:    * Checks whether the client is ready to be marked as ready.
137:    * @returns {void}
138:    */
139:   checkIfReady() {
140:     if (this.status === Constants.Status.READY || this.status === Constants.Status.NEARLY) return false;
141:     let unavailableGuilds = 0;
142:     for (const guild of this.client.guilds.values()) {
143:       if (!guild.available) unavailableGuilds++;
144:     }
145:     if (unavailableGuilds === 0) {
146:       this.status = Constants.Status.NEARLY;
147:       if (!this.client.options.fetchAllMembers) return this.triggerReady();
148:       // Fetch all members before marking self as ready
149:       const promises = this.client.guilds.map(g => g.fetchMembers());
150:       Promise.all(promises)
151:         .then(() => this.triggerReady())
152:         .catch(e => {
153:           this.debug(`Failed to fetch all members before ready! ${e}`);
154:           this.triggerReady();
155:         });
156:     }
157:     return true;
158:   }

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

460: /**
461:    * Identifies as a new connection on the gateway.
462:    * @returns {void}
463:    */
464:   identifyNew() {
465:     if (!this.client.token) {
466:       this.debug('No token available to identify a new session with');
467:       return;
468:     }
469:     // Clone the generic payload and assign the token
470:     const d = Object.assign({ token: this.client.token }, this.client.options.ws);
471: 
472:     // Sharding stuff
473:     const { shardId, shardCount } = this.client.options;
474:     if (shardCount > 0) d.shard = [Number(shardId), Number(shardCount)];
475: 
476:     // Send the payload
477:     this.debug('Identifying as a new session');
478:     this.send({ op: Constants.OPCodes.IDENTIFY, d });
479:   }
```

Looking at my other bots, I don't really see the issue here. Any help would be appreciated and thank you.

Version of Discord.js: v11

Comment: It looks like it’s your typeof client.options.disabledEvents === « object » which creates this error maybe try to check if client is defined first

Comment: yes it did at first and I solved that issue by adding client to `constructor()`.